# How to retrieve the return value from future.get() without blocking the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, future

I have a method to do some background work with a Future. I need to know how to get it's result without blocking the UI thread. Where do I have to do the `future.get()` call?

I've tried to use the method `future.isDone()` in a while loop, but as expected, this also blocks the UI thread.

This is my code:

```java
Future<ArrayList<String>> future = DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks()
                .submit(new Callable<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ArrayList<String> call() {

                        //DO SOME LONG WORK

                        return results;
                    }
                });

        try {
            return future.get();
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

At this moment, the UI just stops in the `future.get()` line waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Why are you calling `get()` if you want the calling site to not be blocked? Can't you just return the `Future`?

Comment: I just want to get the ArrayList<String>. I also tried to use AsyncTask to return it but documentation specifically says: don't use it for long work

Comment: It doesn't make any sense for a thread to call `future.get()` immediately after submitting a task. The whole point of Futures is, Thread T can submit a task, and then it can _do something else_ while the task is being executed by a one of the  thread pool's workers. If there isn't anything else that thread T can do before the task is completed, then it would make more sense for thread T to just perform the task itself instead of giving it to an Executor.

Comment: Re, "I just want to get the ArrayList<>." But, there _isn't_ any ArrayList to be gotten until the "// Do some long work" has finished. The value returned by `get()` is whatever value the long-running task returns. You can't `get()` it until the task returns it. Maybe you should show some more code, and explain _why_ you think you need the `get()` to return right away.